# HipChat: How to fix spelling mistakes in a text with a slash?

Tags: hipchat

To fix a spelling mistake just type `s/<old message>/<new message>`

But this doesn't seem to work if the `<old message>` contains a slash.
Can the slash be escaped somehow? `\/` does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't find any other way then do changes before and after slash separately. If slash was not intended, then it's not possible to remove it.

[HipChat Q/A:](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Questions/How-do-you-edit-slash-quot-hellw-oorld-quot-s-quot-w-o-quot-quot/qaq-p/350400)

> Like you mentioned, slashes are one thing that the current "s///" replace behavior doesn't quite handle. We definitely want to improve the UX here in the future. There are a few public JIRA issues that have been borne from user suggestions - you can follow along at https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/HCPUB-1799 (watch/comment/vote) and you'll get notified of any improvements we make to message editing / deleting in the future.